# Highlight all occurrences of selection in all windows in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

I'm using Visual Studio Code with two windows (panes) side-by-side. To avoid confusion, here is a screenshot:

[image]

I'm using `"editor.selectionHighlight": true`, which you can see is working in the left (active) window. 
A similar solution is proposed in [this question with `editor.action.selectHighlights`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539714/select-all-occurrences-of-selected-word-in-vscode), but that works only in the active window. I tried searching but all my searches resulted in what I'm already using.

When I was using Atom, I was using a "Highlight Selection" plugin which highlighted matches from all open windows.

Is there a way, either native (preferred) or via an extension, to make selection highlighting work in all open windows?

Comment: seems not https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/30014, some comments say the https://github.com/xucongli1989/highlight-icemode extension provides this feature, but it did not work for me

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the highlight (not select) functionality shown below will be released in Stable v1.84 early December 2023 as under this setting:

```
Editor: Occurrences Highlight

Controls whether occurrences should be highlighted across files.
```

Options:

1. `off`
2. `singleFile`  - current file only
3. `multiFile`   - across all valid open files

---

Work has begun and can be tested on this feature in the Insiders Build v1.84.  The currently experimental feature will highlight the occurrences of a word found in all **visible** editors (in my early testing).  From [Test: Multi Editor/Model Highlighting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/196342)

You must enable this setting:

```
Editor: Multi Document Occurrences Highlight

> Experimental: Controls whether the editor should highlight word
> occurrences across multiple open editors
```

Note

> This initial implementation features only textual occurrences, with
> support for semantic highlighting coming in the future.

Here is a demo with three different files in three editor groups.  You see you don't have to select the words, just click on them.

[image: highlight occurrences across files]

Comment: I don't think this is an exact fit to the question? occurrence highlight is a separate thing from selection highlight.

Comment: Mixing "select all occurrences" and "highlight all occurrences" doesn't lead to clarity.  The OP mentions that the setting `editor.selectionHighlight` does what he wants in the current file - but that doesn't `select` those other matches, only highlights them.  The command `selectHighlights` does select them all so it really isn't clear whether the OP wants to select all occurrences in the other files or just highlight them.  In any case, there is no built-in way to select all the matching occurrences in the other files.

Comment: But is there any need to select all the occurrences in both split files?  No, just select them in the one file and any changes there will be reflected in all the other occurrences in the other file.  That is another reason why the OP may be wanting to just highlight but not select those other file matches.

Comment: But I suspect that the OP may not mean split files when he says "side-by-side" given their tab names.