# Search with multiple cursors in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Note: This is **NOT** a duplicate of "[Select all occurrences of selected word in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539714/select-all-occurrences-of-selected-word-in-vscode)

I already have multiple cursors. Imagine `|` are the cursors and I have 3 like this

```
Some Line|Some Text, More Text
Some Other Line|Some Other Text, Other More Text
Yet Another Line|Yet Some Other Text, Yet Other More Text
```

Now I want to move all 3 cursors to the `,` in their respective lines. Ideally I'd like to be able to use a full search to do it as often the search would require more nuance (like first comma that's followed by word that starts with T). This is a problem I would generally solve with keyboard macros in other editors but VSCode doesn't have those and I'm told multiple cursors is the solution yet I have not found a way to do a search for all the cursors

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#move-by) and command `moveby.regex`

You can set it to use a fixed regex to search for or ask you for the regex:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+f6",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.regex",
    "args": {
      "ask": true,
      "properties": ["next", "start"]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview) (disclaimer: I am the author) to do what you want.  Sample keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+f",
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {

    "find": ",(?=\\s*T)",  // the first , followed by a word with a T

    // "replace": "***",

    "isRegex": true,
    "matchCase": true

    // if you want to fine-tuen where the cursor ends up, use postCommands
    // "postCommands": ["cursorLeft", "cursorRight"]

  },
},
```

It works with multiple cursors....  Demo:

[image: go to next regex in document with multiple cursors demo]

Although you might find it easier to use this keybinding instead to cycle through the matches with replace or selection instead (with a single cursor):

```
{
  "key": "alt+f",
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {

    "find": ",(?=\\s*T)",
    // "replace": "***",

    "isRegex": true,
    "matchCase": true,

    // "restrictFind": "line"
    "restrictFind": "nextMoveCursor",

    // "postCommands": ["cursorLeft", "cursorRight"]
  },
},
```