# Select all occurrences of current selection in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

In my VSCode there's nothing option about "Select all occurrences of current selection". How can I add it? or How can I reset the keybinding?

This is my option:
[image: This is my option]

Comment: use menu option **Selection** | **Select All Occurrences**, it should show the keybinding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539714/select-all-occurrences-of-selected-word-in-vscode?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select a part of a text file and execute the command `Select All Occurrences of Find Match` it does the following:

1. Select Part of a Text file
   [image]
2. Execute `Select All Occurrences of Find Match` command from the command menu
   [image]
3. All occurences of the text snippet are now selected and can be edited
   [image]

If you change the keybinding of just the `Select All Occurrences of Find Match` command, this allows you to use that keybinding to do what I just described above.

Comment: I'm sorry if you're confused, but I mean "Multi-selection", not "Find Match". There is no option for "Multi-selection".

Comment: Okay but executing `Select All Occurrences of Find Match` on a selection *does* mutliselect all occurences. So it does "Select all occurrences of current selection".

Comment: Oh, I see. But I did what you told,it still doesn't work. Thank you for answering.

Comment: I have added screenshots to my post.