# Keep only an element of a webpage while web-scraping

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to extract a table from a webpage with python. I managed to get all the contents inside of that table, but since I am very new to webscrapping I don't know how to keep only the elements that I am looking for.

I know that I should look for this class in the code: `<a class="_3BFvyrImF3et_ZF21Xd8SC"`, which specify the items in the table.

So how can I keep only those classes to then extract the title of them?

```
<a class="_3BFvyrImF3et_ZF21Xd8SC" title="r/Python" href="/r/Python/">r/Python</a>
<a class="_3BFvyrImF3et_ZF21Xd8SC" title="r/Java" href="/r/Java/">r/Java</a>
```

I miserably failed in writing a code for that. I don't know how I could extract only these classes, so any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to find elements by class name? Try 
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002313/finding-elements-by-class-name-with-selenium-in-python

Comment: What library are you using to scrape the webpage and transform the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the value of *`title`* attributes you can use [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72565083/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("title") for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a._3BFvyrImF3et_ZF21Xd8SC[title]")])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("title") for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='_3BFvyrImF3et_ZF21Xd8SC' and @title]")])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have made a very simple thing that worked.

Basically I pasted the code on VSCODE and the selected all the occurrences of that class. Then I just had to copy and paste in another file. Not sure why the shortcut CTRL + Shift + L did not work, but I have managed to get what I needed.

[Select all occurrences of selected word in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539714/select-all-occurrences-of-selected-word-in-vscode)